# POST array in php not showing all the elements

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a form that post to a php page, The desired outcome is a `count($_POST['amount]) = 200`,but I am getting the count of 167 instead of 200 ,cannot identify the cause.

**If I remove the column squrefootage from table, then I get the correct count.**

Can someone tell me the reason?

Here is the code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/yBtwSA

Comment: do not post a link to your code. copy the relevant code here. noone will bother following url's to study your code.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Comment: The php code is higher than the limit of stackoverflow body,so I have to post a link because the whole code is needed to explain my problem

Comment: can any one tell me the reasons for down votes?

Comment: **Down voters** the link instead of embeded code is because stack overflow doesnt allow more than 30,000 characters but the question is more important! **So please review the questions php code first before downvoting**!

Comment: Then paste a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What does `echo ini_get('max_input_vars')` give?

Comment: After `max_input_vars`, check `post_max_size` as well

Comment: @Eirenaios I [rejected your attempted edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6098214) because it was intended as a comment/reply (as you've already done). The post size limit is there for a *reason*. As ʰᵈˑ said, that's what [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is for.

Comment: okay peace!................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**`max_input_vars`**](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) *integer*
>
> How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` superglobal
>   separately). Use of this directive mitigates the possibility of denial
>   of service attacks which use hash collisions. If there are more input
>   variables than specified by this directive, an `E_WARNING` is issued,
>   and **further input variables are truncated from the request.**

Set the `max_input_vars` to a bigger number.

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 5000);
```

I also notice in your code that you're nesting a lot of values.

> **[`max_input_nesting_level`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max_input_nesting_level)** *integer*
>
> Sets the max nesting depth of input variables (i.e. `$_GET`, `$_POST`..)

```
ini_set('max_input_nesting_level', 5000);
```

It may be better if you do this within your `php.ini` file. If you do, make sure you restart. `sudo service httpd restart` (assuming you're running Apache)